# Копирование файлов на запасной сервер по scp

Tags: cron, резервное-копирование

Здравствуйте. Вопрос из разряда "у всех работает, а у меня - нет".
Настраиваю копирование файлов на запасной сервак по scp.

в cron.d:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
30 0 * * * root /root/scp
```

в /root/scp:

```
scp -r /home/aaa/*  root@1.1.1.1:/var/www/aaa/
```

Создал ssh ключи. Если запускать из командной строки скрипт - пароль не требуется.

В /var/log/cron:

```
Jun 28 00:30:01 sss CROND[11806]: (root) CMD (/root/scp)
```

Но файлы не копируются. В чём может быть дело, подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо '`scp`' в файле `/root/scp` вставить то, что скажет '`which scp`'